# How to save objects in onPause()?

Tags: android, multithreading

The app I'm building has two worker threads, one for networking and one just for receiving network data. The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how to save the `Socket`, `BufferedReader`, and `PrintWriter` objects from the networking thread before I close it in `onPause()`. I don't need the objects to persist, I just need a way to save them in a way that doesn't leave the worker threads running if Android kills the activity in `onPause()`. Is there a way to save these objects to a Bundle for `onSaveInstanceState()`, or is there another way (like `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, but not just for config changes)? Also, will Android automatically close all of an application's threads if it kills the activity? That would solve my problem as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few questions in there. I will try to answer a few.

`Threads`, `Sockets`, `BufferedReader`s and `PrintWriter`s cannot be Parceled. You can parcel a file descriptor but sadly not these complex types. These complex types have a lot of state and that would be hard to parcel to a bundle without knowing the implementation of each.

`onPause()` is not the same as a kill. `onPause` simply means your process is not going to be running foreground. So you basically will have no view. However your threads will still be there, and running unless you do something to them. If you are going to manage your own threads, I would recommend keeping references to them so that you can call `interrupt()` on them when you need them to stop. (Or if you extended the thread, have some sort of exit condition in it's run method that can be triggered by some custom method on it)

if your app is truly killed, then yes your threads are killed too.

Comment: I know that `onPause()` is different from a kill, but the android documentation says that the application could be killed at any time after `onPause()`, without necessarily calling `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` (for example, by the out-of-memory killer). If the activity is destroyed in this way, will the threads automatically be destroyed or do I need to stop them in `onPause()` first just in case?

Comment: Thank you. I also realized that I can save the threads' state to public variables in `onPause()` but I won't need to if Android will kill the threads for me along with the activity if it closes it.

Answer (score 0):

you can override onPause() method on your code and save the data on shared preferences when the onPause() event is triggered.